# C++ Load two versions of Qt5GUI.dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll, dllimport

I've readed a similar question (and reply) here: [Can I use two incompatible versions of the same DLL in the same process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315285/can-i-use-two-incompatible-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-the-same-process)
But I cannot modify the Qt5Gui.dll file as was done by that user.

My problem comes from using Maya software that uses and includes that library at 5.6 version and I need to create a new plugin dll that uses 5.7 version of Qt5Gui (its needed by third party libraries) and when I try to load that 5.7 one its sure that 5.6 is already loaded so executing

```
    mModule = LoadLibraryEx(absDllPath, NULL, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
```

returns error 127: The specified procedure could not be found.

The weird thing is that Qt5Core and others were loaded ok.

Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: Don't think this will work out at all.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve such problem by delegating the Maya's tasks to a sub-process that a plugin dll would create and interact with that sub-process by means of `RPC`, `pipes` or `shared memory` or combination of them. This allows the `Qt` v5.7 dll to be accessible directly in the plugin dll while `Qt` v5.6 is only needed for Maya to function correctly.

**Edit:** As you commented further that only one of dependency `dll`s requires `Qt` v5.7 the split may be different: if that `dll` provides less data/services to your plugin than `Maya`, then it might be more proper to create a sub-process to host that `dll` instead of `Maya`.

Comment: The idea is more or less like that I mean my dll is something like a loader for other dlls and routines, the problem is that one of that needed dlls requires Qt 5.7 so I cannot load it properly or you mean a separate .exe (instead a .dll) that shares memory?

Comment: yes, I mean a separate .exe if that terminology is more clearer to you